# Tomcat: Website not available after setup SSL

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

my server.xml is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!--<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />-->

  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
  <GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">

   <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
           keystoreFile="c:\*****.jks"
           keystorePass="*****" />
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8444" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>

      <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="subit.biz" unpackWARs="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" 
            pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" 
            prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"/>
        <Context path="" docBase="MoneyTransferMember"/>   
        <Alias>subit.biz</Alias>
        <Alias>www.subit.biz</Alias>
      </Host>         
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

When I finished setup and then restart tomcat, my server start normally, no exception, but I can access my website(https://localhost,https://subit.biz).
If I use

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    enter code here
```

My website will start normally.